# Java массив из значений функции

Tags: java, ооп

Вот у меня есть код табулирования функции:

```
public static void Tabul() {
    for (double i = 0.2; i <= 2.8; i = i + 0.002) {
        double y;
        final double a = 2.3;
        if (i < 0.3) {
            y = 1.5 * a * pow(cos(i), 2);
        } 
        else if (i < 2.3) {
            y = pow((i - 2), 2) + 6 * a;
        } 
        else {
            y = 3 * a * tan(i);
        }
        System.out.println("x= " + i + "  y=" + y);
    }
}
```

Теперь мне надо создать метод `private` со значениями `у` как значениями элемента массива.
Как это сделать я не могу понять. Подскажите. пожалуйста!

Comment: Уточните, что вы понимаете под "методом `private` со значениями `у` как значениями элемента массива".

Comment: Я перепутала, мне надо не только х, но и у.

Comment: Я создала счетчик, как написано в задании. Он считает сколько шагов табулирования:

`   public static void KTabul(){
      int k=0;
      for (double i=0.2; i<=2.8; i=i+0.002 ) {
         k++;
      }`

Answer (score 1):

Т.е вам нужно сохранить все значения y ?

если да то просто переопределите y на массив размерностью в количество точек, а именно (в вашем случае)

```
double[] y = new double[(int)((2.8 - 0.2)/0.002)];
```

и дополнительнуюю переменную для инкремента. В итоге остаётся заменить y на y[z++] = ...

где z - переменная типа int обьявленная до начала цикла и равная изначально нулю.

Comment: Забыл `+1` у размера массива.